# Крашится приложение после обновы Android Studio

Tags: java, android

```
public class FragmentCatalog extends Fragment {
    View view;
    @BindView(R.id.listView)
    ListView listView;
    @BindView(R.id.tabLayout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.share2x).setText("Поделиться"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.save2x).setText("Сохранить"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.calculate2x).setText("Калькулятор"));
        new Async().execute();
        return view;
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class Async extends AsyncTask{
        JSONArray jsonArrayResponse;
        int intDrawables[] = {R.drawable.f2x, R.drawable.ff2x, R.drawable.land2x, R.drawable.rooms2x, R.drawable.square2x};
        String stringDrawablesName[] = {"", "", "land", "rooms", "square"};
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        int indexDrawables=0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка данных");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            try {
                String str=HttpRequest.get("http://app.maralin.ru/application.php?type=catalog&action=list&limit=10&page=1")
                        .getResponse().getResponseText();
                jsonArrayResponse=new JSONArray(new JSONObject(str));
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return jsonArrayResponse.length();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int i) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int i) {
                    return 0;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog_adap, viewGroup, false);
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    try {
                    JSONArray jsonArrayDops=jsonArrayResponse.getJSONObject(position).getJSONArray("dops");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayDops.length(); i++) {
                            String nameImageIcon=jsonArrayDops.getJSONObject(i).getString("key");
                            for (int j = 0; j < stringDrawablesName.length; j++) {
                                if (nameImageIcon.equals(stringDrawablesName[j])){
                                    indexDrawables=j;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                            textView.setText(jsonArrayDops.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"));
                            textView.setTextSize(12);
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                            imageView.setImageResource(intDrawables[indexDrawables]);
                            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                            linearLayout.addView(textView);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                    return view;
                }
            });

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Данный код был рабочий недавно. После обновления - стал крашиться. Ни как не могу понять в чем проблема.

Уже и чистил проект и гуглил и все что можно. Все бесполезно.

---

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.<init>
                                                                             at com.eranewgames.maralinru.Fragments.FragmentCatalog$Async.doInBackground(FragmentCatalog.java:68)
```

Тут курсор останавливается

```
        jsonArrayResponse=new JSONArray(new JSONObject(str));
```

---

```
compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

---

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.<init>
                                                                               at com.eranewgames.maralinru.Fragments.FragmentCatalog$Async.doInBackground(FragmentCatalog.java:65)
```

Comment: а проблема на всех устройствах? Выглядит как будто системную библиотеку не подгрузило. Чистку проекта пробовали делать? Какая targetSdkVersion/compileSdkVersion в проекте?

Comment: Тестировал на Genymotion API 16.

Comment: попробуйте на реальном устройстве запустить, или targetSdkVersion понизить.

Comment: @pavel, Офигеть просто. 3 часа в никуда. Таргет поменял на 23 как вы и сказали. Спасибо вам.
Я **** *** Google!!!